# select file(s) with certain extension from disk

Tags: c#, .net

let's say that I want to check certain file exist on file system and I want to check if that file exist with certain file extension (those are image file extensions).

This file will always have string prefix `thumb-` followed with dynamic id value of type int.

I have

```
string[] fileExtensions = new string[] { ".jpg", ".png", ".bmp", "gif" };
```

I was thinking to use DirectoryInfo but I'm struggling with contains part

```
var f = from f in di.EnumerateFiles(string.Format("{0}{1}.*", "thumb-", id))
                        where f.Extension.Contains(fileExtensions)
                        select f;
```

obviously where f.Extension.Contains(fileExtensions) is where error is.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a better solution:

```
var files = di.EnumerateFiles(string.Format("{0}{1}.*", "thumb-", id))
            .Where(x => fileExtensions.Contains(x.Extension));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var files=di.GetFiles(string.Format("{0}{1}.*", "thumb-", id))
            .Where(x=>fileExtensions.Any(y=>y==x.Extension));
```